# How to get the session value, tempdata in external JavaScript file in asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to access the session value in external js file. I have tried,

```
var userid = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]';
```

this dosen't work as the variable userid take the right hand side as a string.  Can anyone suggest me a idea.

Comment: You cant. Razor code is not parsed in external files. You need to assign the value to a variable in the main view and pass it to the function in the external file (or use a global variable)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `Session` variable in `.cshtml` and pass it to external javascript file by calling function of external `.js` file.

```
var userid = '@Session["UserID"]';
externalJsFunction(userid);
```

You can assign session to some hidden field and get the hidden field value (session value) in document.ready in external js file.

Comment: I dn't want to have any javascript variables declared in the .cshtml as I want to minify the js file later. So, at this situation will this be useful??

Comment: You can directly pass session like externalJsFunction(@Session["UserID"]'); What impact this would have if you minify? or You can assign session to some hidden field and get the hidden field value (session value) in document.ready in external js file.

Comment: I dn't want the user to view the value when they inspect element in the or when they debug the script in the browser.

Comment: There is no way you can hide value on client side as far as I know.

Comment: Thank u adil..Is it the same case for passing tempdata?

Comment: TempData has different behavior than Session but you can access that in javascript as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution for you.
In layout of your website define any empty div and set its data attribute value with session value if you are using html5 as,

```
<div id="sessionDiv" data-id="@Session["UserID"]"></div>
```

Now in your external js file access this div.

```
var userid=$('#sessionDiv').attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `script` tag at the top of the `.cshtml` file and assign a the `userid` to a global variable. This variable is then accessible in all javascript files.

**index.cshtml**

```
...
<script>
    document.mynamespace = {};
    document.mynamespace.userid = '@HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]';
</script>
....
```

**javascript.js**

```
var userid = document.mynamespace.userid;  //do something with userid
```

mynamespace is a proxy object so that you dont pollute the global namespace.